# How to separate nested islands from the sea in ANTLR4?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to implement an ANTLR4 grammar for a quite simple language, that extends the one from [StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) (but I'm using C#, so this library is no bueno). Basically it allows substitutions in a regular text, e.g.

```
text ${aaa}${/asd/${yyy}} goes on ${fff} and on
```

So that there can be tokens like `${id}` or `${/some/path}` and the path can also contain nested guys like `${/asd/${yyy}}`. In a real case there are even more similar constructs and escape chars, but let's skip them for simplicity.

Now I managed to write a grammar for all these cases except for having a regular text around the outermost expressions:

```
lexer grammar LocalExpressionLexer;

BEGIN : '${';
END : '}';
SPACE          : [ \t\r\n]-> skip;

ID : [0-9a-zA-Z_]+;
PATH_SEPARATOR : '/';

LOCAL_EXPRESSION
 : BEGIN -> more, pushMode(IN_LOCAL_EXPR) 
 ;

mode IN_LOCAL_EXPR;
  LOCAL_EXPR_END : END -> more, popMode;
```

and parser:

```
parser grammar LocalExpressionParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=LocalExpressionLexer;
}

parse
 : (atom)+ EOF
 ;

atom
 : BEGIN (localVariable | path) END
 ;

localVariable
 : ID;
 
path
 : (PATH_SEPARATOR (atom | ID))+
 ;
```

It draws the following graph for the above text (with surrounding text removed):
[image: graph without stray text]

In order to allow surrounding text around outermost `${}` tokens I followed roughly the XML example from *The definitive ANTLR4 reference* book, where concept of *islands in the sea* was introduced. It goes like we have a sea of a surrounding text with "islands" of XML tags and when `<` char is encountered, then we `pushMode()` and use different lexer rules for pure XML tag processing (e.g. attributes).

Using similar concept I came up with the following lexer:

```
lexer grammar LocalExpressionLexer;

BEGIN : '${';
END : '}';
SPACE          : [ \t\r\n]-> skip;

ID : [0-9a-zA-Z_]+;
PATH_SEPARATOR : '/';

LOCAL_EXPRESSION
 : BEGIN -> more, pushMode(IN_LOCAL_EXPR) 
 ;

TEXT
 : ~[$]+
 ;
  
mode IN_LOCAL_EXPR;
  LOCAL_EXPR_END : END -> more, popMode;
```

and parser

```
parser grammar LocalExpressionParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=LocalExpressionLexer;
}

parse
 : (atom | text)+ EOF
 ;

atom
 : BEGIN (localVariable | path) END
 ;

localVariable
 : ID;
 
path
 : (PATH_SEPARATOR (atom | ID))+
 ;

text
 : TEXT
 ;
```

The problem is that my `TEXT` lexer rule for surrounding text keeps jumping in even in this pushed mode and it turns all my IDs into `TEXT` token which is not recognised by the parser rules. I thought that the `LOCAL_EXPRESSION` rule that pushes mode should precede `TEXT` and then use token rules from `IN_LOCAL_EXPR` mode instead, but apparently not, see the graph:

[image: graph with stray text attempt]

Please note, that all tokens, that should be interpreted by `localVariable` or `path` parser rules occur twice, once as the wrapping `atom` with plain `ID` lexer type and secondly as `text`.

So my question is, how to fix this to be correctly interpreted as `localVariable` and `path` tokens, while also retaining the surrounding text as `text` parser rule (or whatever else)?

Answer (score 0):

Two main issues.

- You need to define your lever rules for your `IN_LOCAL_EXPR` underneath your `mode IN_LOCAL_EXPR` so that they are rules for that mode.
- When you do this (since you allow nesting), you'll need to recreate your `BEGIN` rule in the `IN_LOCAL_EXPR` mode (you can use the `type` Lexer action to create the same token to keep the parser simpler.

With the following Lexer rules (and your sample input):

```
lexer grammar LocalExpressionLexer
    ;

BEGIN: '${' -> pushMode(IN_LOCAL_EXPR);

TEXT: ~[$]+;

mode IN_LOCAL_EXPR
    ;

ID: [0-9a-zA-Z_]+;

PATH_SEPARATOR: '/';

LE_BEGIN: '${' -> type(BEGIN), pushMode(IN_LOCAL_EXPR);

SPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

END: '}' -> popMode;
```

I get this parse tree:

[image: parse tree]